# Whats the best way to open socket with angular +2?

Tags: angular

I'am using stopjs and socket-client like this :
I got an error says that cant use the ws: protocol and needs me to change it with the http: or https is their is another solution to implement socket ?

````
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import { WebsocketService } from './websocket.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 private serverUrl = 'ws://192.168.1.50:8085/endpoint/socket';

 constructor() {
   this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
 }
 initializeWebSocketConnection() {
   let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl); 
   this.stompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, ws);
   // this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
   let that = this;
   this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
     that.isLoaded = true;
     console.log('Connected !')
     console.log(frame)
   });
 }

}
}```
````

Comment: why the java tag?

Comment: the back-end implemented with java the the same libs